# Loading either all shops or a specifically named shop from a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

```
public  delegate DataTable loadDataTable();

DataTable shops = (cmbShop.Text == "All Shops") ? 
      new loadDataTable(() =>
       {
       Program.con.GET_Table_From_DataBase("sh", "select * from shops ");
       return Program.con.dst.Tables["sh"];
       }
      ).Invoke()
     :
       new loadDataTable(() =>
       {
        Program.con.GET_Table_From_DataBase("sh", "select * from shops where shopname='" +  cmbShop.Text + "' ");
        return Program.con.dst.Tables["sh"];
       }
  ).Invoke();
```

I am just setting the value of `DataTable shops` here.

I am learning about lambda expressions, so just for learning purposes, I want to know if this code can be shortened while using lambda expressions.

Comment: Why on earth would you use a lambda expression here?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Any code which has `combobox.Text` near `GetTableFromDatabase` can be *optimized*

Comment: @Slakes  will you please explain(You have a SQL injection vulnerability)

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: To answer the original question, yes they can, e.g. with [this](https://thorium.github.io/Linq.Expression.Optimizer/) or [this](http://nessos.github.io/LinqOptimizer/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need any lambda expressions at all.

You can write

```
if (cmbShop.Text == "All Shops")
    Program.con.GET_Table_From_DataBase("sh", "select * from shops ");
else
    Program.con.GET_Table_From_DataBase("sh", "select * from shops where shopname='" +  cmbShop.Text + "' ");

DataTable shops = Program.con.dst.Tables["sh"];
```

Comment: You can move 
everything except second parameter out of the `if` statement.

Comment: no `{}` - this needs a review ;-P

Answer (score 1):

Using lambda expressions here are a bit of overkill.

Though I think this goes overboard (imho) on the ternary operator:

```
 Program.con.GET_Table_FromDataBase("sh", string.Format("select * from shops{0}", 
                 (cmbShop.Text == "All Shops") ? string.Empty : string.Format(" where shopname='"+cmbShop.Text+"'"));
```

As others stated, I would reconsider how you are fetching your data. The current method might leave you exposed for a world of hurt. :) Changing your approach on data access will, more than likely, also change how you are building your queries so a lot of this would be moot.